# How can I display x amount of items from array when searching then narrowing down the content?

Tags: javascript, html, tailwind-css, alpine.js

I am trying to implement a search bar similar to that of Steam, where it has an entire array of games, but it will initially show a few results, until you narrow down your search result. So far this is what I have:

data

```
<nav class="flex flex-row justify-between p-8">
  <div class="flex flex-row gap-8 items-center">
    <img class="cursor-pointer w-12 h-12" src="../static/Bars Menu.svg" />
    <a href="{{ url_for('games_bp.browse_games', page = 0) }}" class="font-sans text-primary font-black text-5xl">
      Steamli
    </a>
  </div>

  <!-- Search Bar with Dropdown -->
  <div class="position: relative z-50" x-data="{
        search: '',
        isOpen: false,
        items: [
          'Call of Duty', 'Grand Theft Auto', 'Need for Speed', 'CSGO', 'World of Warcraft', 'Armenian Genocide',
          'FIFA 22', 'Assassin\'s Creed Valhalla', 'Cyberpunk 2077', 'The Witcher 3', 'Red Dead Redemption 2', 'Minecraft',
          'Halo Infinite', 'Battlefield 2042', 'Fall Guys', 'Among Us', 'Valorant', 'Fortnite', 'Apex Legends'
        ],
        itemImages: [
          'image1.jpg', 'image2.jpg', 'image3.jpg', 'image4.jpg', 'image5.jpg', 'image6.jpg',
          'image7.jpg', 'image8.jpg', 'image9.jpg', 'image10.jpg', 'image11.jpg', 'image12.jpg',
          'image13.jpg', 'image14.jpg', 'image15.jpg', 'image16.jpg', 'image17.jpg', 'image18.jpg', 'image19.jpg',
        ],
        itemPrices: [
          '$49.99', '$29.99', '$39.99', '$19.99', '$59.99', '$9.99',
          '$39.99', '$49.99', '$59.99', '$29.99', '$59.99', '$19.99',
          '$59.99', '$49.99', '$19.99', '$9.99', '$19.99', '$9.99', '$29.99',
        ]
      }">
```

html/tailwind

```
    enter code here
    <!-- Search bar code -->
    <div class="relative">
      <input
        x-on:click="isOpen = true"
        x-on:input.debounce.300ms="isOpen = true"
        x-model="search"
        placeholder="Search Here..."
        class="py-3 px-4 w-64 rounded shadow font-thin focus:outline-none focus:shadow-lg focus:shadow-slate-200 duration-100 shadow-gray-100"
      />
      <div
        x-show="isOpen"
        x-transition:enter="transition ease-out duration-300"
        x-transition:enter-start="opacity-0 translate"
        x-transition:enter-end="opacity-100 translate"
        x-transition:leave="transition ease-in duration-300"
        x-transition:leave-start="opacity-100 translate"
        x-transition:leave-end="opacity-0 translate"
        class="absolute top-full right-0 mt-2 w-64 bg-white border rounded-lg shadow-lg"
      >
        <ul>
<!-- producing each row -->
          <template x-for="item in items" :key="item">
            <li class="flex w-full text-gray-700 p-4" x-show="item.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())">
              <img :src="itemImages[$index]" class="w-4 h-4 mr-2" alt="Tiny Image" />
              <div class="flex flex-col">
                <span x-text="item"></span>
                <span class="text-sm text-gray-500" x-text="itemPrices[$index]"></span>
              </div>
            </li>
          </template>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End of Search Bar -->
  </div>
  <!-- End of Search Bar with Dropdown -->

  <img class="cursor-pointer drop-shadow-xl w-20 h-20 bg-secondary rounded-full border-primary border-8" src="../static/undraw_profile_pic_re_iwgo.svg" />
</nav>

<!-- Rest of your HTML content -->
<script src="//unpkg.com/alpinejs" defer></script>
```

So at the moment, it is displaying the entire array as such:

[image]

When a user types in 'c', it narrows down the search to the following:

[image]

Finally, when you type 'cr' the results are the following:

[image]

It all works nice and fine, except the fact it displays all 20. I keep having the problem, when I display the first 6 results, it then will only search through those 6 items, instead of the array.

If anyone could propose some solution that would be wonderful.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue seems to be because you're directly using the `"x-show"` directive to filter items based on the user's input. This will cause the list to only show those items to match the user's input, and when you try to limit the list to a set number, it won't search through all the items anyore.

I'd create a new array based on the user's search and then use this new array to display the results.

Here is your updated code that should handle this functionality:

```
<nav class="flex flex-row justify-between p-8">
  <div class="flex flex-row gap-8 items-center">
    <img class="cursor-pointer w-12 h-12" src="../static/Bars Menu.svg" />
    <a href="{{ url_for('games_bp.browse_games', page = 0) }}" class="font-sans text-primary font-black text-5xl">
      Steamli
    </a>
  </div>

  <!-- Search Bar with Dropdown -->
  <div class="position: relative z-50" x-data="{
        search: '',
        isOpen: false,
        maxResults: 6, // Number of items to display initially
        items: [
          'Call of Duty', 'Grand Theft Auto', 'Need for Speed', 'CSGO', 'World of Warcraft', 'Armenian Genocide',
          'FIFA 22', 'Assassin\'s Creed Valhalla', 'Cyberpunk 2077', 'The Witcher 3', 'Red Dead Redemption 2', 'Minecraft',
          'Halo Infinite', 'Battlefield 2042', 'Fall Guys', 'Among Us', 'Valorant', 'Fortnite', 'Apex Legends'
        ],
        itemImages: [
          'image1.jpg', 'image2.jpg', 'image3.jpg', 'image4.jpg', 'image5.jpg', 'image6.jpg',
          'image7.jpg', 'image8.jpg', 'image9.jpg', 'image10.jpg', 'image11.jpg', 'image12.jpg',
          'image13.jpg', 'image14.jpg', 'image15.jpg', 'image16.jpg', 'image17.jpg', 'image18.jpg', 'image19.jpg'
        ],
        itemPrices: [
          '$49.99', '$29.99', '$39.99', '$19.99', '$59.99', '$9.99',
          '$39.99', '$49.99', '$59.99', '$29.99', '$59.99', '$19.99',
          '$59.99', '$49.99', '$19.99', '$9.99', '$19.99', '$9.99', '$29.99'
        ],
        get filteredItems() {
            // Filter items based on user input
            const result = this.items.filter(item => item.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase()));
            
            // Return up to maxResults items
            return result.slice(0, this.maxResults);
        }
      }">

    <!-- Search bar code -->
    <div class="relative">
      <input
        x-on:click="isOpen = true"
        x-on:input.debounce.300ms="isOpen = true"
        x-model="search"
        placeholder="Search Here..."
        class="py-3 px-4 w-64 rounded shadow font-thin focus:outline-none focus:shadow-lg focus:shadow-slate-200 duration-100 shadow-gray-100"
      />
      <div
        x-show="isOpen"
        x-transition:enter="transition ease-out duration-300"
        x-transition:enter-start="opacity-0 translate"
        x-transition:enter-end="opacity-100 translate"
        x-transition:leave="transition ease-in duration-300"
        x-transition:leave-start="opacity-100 translate"
        x-transition:leave-end="opacity-0 translate"
        class="absolute top-full right-0 mt-2 w-64 bg-white border rounded-lg shadow-lg"
      >
        <ul>
          <template x-for="(item, index) in filteredItems" :key="item">
            <li class="flex w-full text-gray-700 p-4">
              <img :src="itemImages[index]" class="w-4 h-4 mr-2" alt="Tiny Image" />
              <div class="flex flex-col">
                <span x-text="item"></span>
                <span class="text-sm text-gray-500" x-text="itemPrices[index]"></span>
              </div>
            </li>
          </template>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End of Search Bar -->
  </div>
  <!-- End of Search Bar with Dropdown -->

  <img class="cursor-pointer drop-shadow-xl w-20 h-20 bg-secondary rounded-full border-primary border-8" src="../static/undraw_profile_pic_re_iwgo.svg" />
</nav>

<!-- Rest of your HTML content -->
<script src="//unpkg.com/alpinejs" defer></script>
```

I've modified your `x-data` object to include a computed `filteredItems` property that contains the top `n` results matching the search, it'll then display those results.

Comment: fckin legend. thats all i can say